# xslt conditional increment

Tags: templates, xslt, sorting, conditional-statements, increment

I'm having problems incrementing a counter under certain conditions.

Input:

```
<Users>
  <User>
    <id>1</id>
    <username>jack</username>
  </User>
  <User>
    <id>2</id>
    <username>bob</username>
  </User>
  <User>
    <id>3</id>
    <username>bob</username>
  </User>
  <User>
    <id>4</id>
    <username>jack</username>
  </User>
</Users>
```

Wanted Output:

```
<Users>
  <User>
    <id>1</id>
    <username>jack01</username>
  </User>
  <User>
    <id>2</id>
    <username>bob01</username>
  </User>
  <User>
    <id>3</id>
    <username>bob02</username>
  </User>
  <User>
    <id>4</id>
    <username>jack02</username>
  </User>
</Users>
```

To accomplish this following algorithm can be used:

- sort input by username
- for each user

  - when previous username is equals current username

    - increment counter and
    - set username to '$username$counter'
  - otherwise

    - set counter to 1
- (sort by id again - not really necessary)

So i tried to transform this into XSLT:

```
  <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
      xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

  <xsl:template match="Users">
    <Users>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="create_user">
      <xsl:sort select="User/username"/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
    </Users>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="create_user">
    <id><xsl:value-of select="id"/></id>
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="username=(preceding-sibling::User[1]//username)">
        <xsl:variable name="count">
          <xsl:number format="01"/>
        </xsl:variable>
        <username><xsl:value-of select="concat(username, $count)"/></username>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:variable name="count">
          <xsl:number value="1" format="01"/>
        </xsl:variable>
        <username><xsl:value-of select="concat(username, $count)"/></username>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

However, by executing this i get following errors:

- usernames do not sort
- counter does not increment

  - instead when condition matches counter will be the current node-position.
  - for our example the node with id = 3 would have the username = bob03
- the  tag is missing

Any thoughts?

Comment: I'm confused - does "Output" refer to what you are getting or what you would *like* to be getting?

Comment: "Output" does refer to "Wanted Output". *Edited*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="username/text()">
  <xsl:value-of select="."/>
  <xsl:value-of select=
  "format-number(count(../../preceding-sibling::*[username=current()])+1,
                '00')
  "/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<Users>
    <User>
        <id>1</id>
        <username>jack</username>
    </User>
    <User>
        <id>2</id>
        <username>bob</username>
    </User>
    <User>
        <id>3</id>
        <username>bob</username>
    </User>
    <User>
        <id>4</id>
        <username>jack</username>
    </User>
</Users>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
<Users>
   <User>
      <id>1</id>
      <username>jack01</username>
   </User>
   <User>
      <id>2</id>
      <username>bob01</username>
   </User>
   <User>
      <id>3</id>
      <username>bob02</username>
   </User>
   <User>
      <id>4</id>
      <username>jack02</username>
   </User>
</Users>
```

Comment: Without even sorting? I'm impressed! Thanks for your solution!

Comment: Just out of interest. For each node you look back at every preceding-sibling. On huge data this would take some time. By sorting and just checking the previous node this would be much more efficient. Is there an easy way to accomplish this with XSLT?

Comment: @rednammoc, Yes, but this would require a two - pass transformation and in XSLT 1.0 this also requires the use of the `xxx:node-set()` extension function. If you just sort all `User` by their `username`, the result has a different ordering than that of the original document -- I believe, you don't want to change the original ordering. So, if you specify those details in a new question, an efficient solution is possible.

Comment: thanks. i've posted a follow up [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13727201/efficient-xslt-conditional-increment)

Answer (score 0):

"Incrementing a counter" isn't what you do in a functional programming language. You need to describe the output you want as a function of the input (as Dimitre has done), rather than describing a process or procedure for computing the output.