# Is XSLT always applicable?

Tags: xslt

This is just a question that arose out of curiosity.

Can anyone give an example of a problem related to processing of XML that cannot be solved using XSLT templates?

Comment: There are unsolvable problems (e.g. the halting problem), and XML is probably complex enough to encode arithmetic or turing machines....

Comment: It has been proven that XSLT is Turing - complete. Threfore, there isn't anything that "can't be done with XSLT. On the other side, the really unsolvable problems are those, where certain data is not part of the static context of the transformation. For example, an XSLT 1.0 transformation cannot determine what is the current time and date. An XSLT 2.0 transformation can't determine what time has elapsed at a given point in the transformation, form the start of the transformation, ..., etc.

Answer (score 1):

It isn't fair to declare saying 'a particular calculation or a particular kind of operation isn't possible with a given language'.. because there will be a guy somewhere in the world who provides an extension and proves it to be possible :)

Well. XSLT is meant to tranform XML to desired format like XML/HTML/Text (that includes generating CSV files as well) And XSLT is perfect in that!!

Sharing my personal experience, I faced few operations sound to be difficult with XSLT 1.0.. Example: datetime operations(adding subtracting two datetime values). But fortunately msxsl supports inline scripting, which solved my problem!

Why don't you give try to achieve something out of your imagination.. if you are stuck somewhere then let fellow members have good time solving such puzzles :)

Answer (score 1):

Processing an XML document is often really a case of processing two things- the structure of the document itself, and the content within the various nodes.

For example, if you want to do a regex replace on all `foo` nodes using XSLT 1.0, writing a template that matches those nodes is easy, but actually doing a regex replace on the content is VERY hard to do, you'd need to write your own regex parser. In a case like this, it makes far more sense to have the host language obtain a list of nodes with XPath, and handle the replace itself.

Secondly, some solutions just aren't efficient in XSLT. Take this question for example: [efficient xslt conditional increment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13727201/efficient-xslt-conditional-increment), although what the OP asked was of course entirely possible, XSLT isn't the most efficient language to do it in. I could easily have done that far more efficiently in a single pass using a procedural language.

The other argument of course is really about maintainability- you write code that your team will be able to maintain. If nobody else in your team knows XSLT, in the short term you're probably better off using what they know (although having them learn XSLT is ALWAYS a good plan, if you've got the time/budget).