# Row Number in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

There is one XML file that contains duplicate Ids.

I want to add some row number based on that duplicate IDs.

Example XML File like below :

```
<ROOT>
<record1>
        <ID>123</ID>
        <Name>abc</Name>
</record1>
<record2>
        <ID>123</ID>
        <Name>def</Name>
</record2>
<record3>
        <ID>456</ID>
        <Name>ghi</Name>
</record3>
</ROOT>
```

I need this in following format ::

```
<ROOT>
<record1>
        <ID>123_1</ID>
        <Name>abc</Name>
</record1>
<record2>
        <ID>123_2</ID>
        <Name>def</Name>
</record2>
<record3>
        <ID>456</ID>
        <Name>ghi</Name>
</record3>
</ROOT>
```

Can any put me in right way, how to write a XSL for this ?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried *anything* yourself already? If not, why not?

Comment: I found a similar thread to your problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13714647/xslt-conditional-increment

Comment: I have a solution for you, but I have to agree with @Tomalak - in the interest of helping you learn, I'd love to see what you've already tried.

Answer (score 0):

If you add this template to an XSLT identity transform, you should be all set:

```
<xsl:template match="ID">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:value-of select"." />
        <xsl:if test="//ID[. = current()]">
              <xsl:value-of select="concat('_', count(preceding::ID[. = current()]) + 1)" />
        </xsl:when>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: I think this answer could benefit from some explanation, specifically if it is to apply to similar problems. Specifically what does `. = current()` do in this context?